# Find k for which the equation has equal roots.

Tags: functions, quadratics

I find to find the value of k in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ .
I rearranged the equation $x^2
+kx-1=2k+x$ into $x^2+(k-1)x-(1+2k)=0.$

I then found $\alpha$$\beta$ to equal$-1-2k$.
and $\alpha + \beta$ to equal $-k+1.$

I was then asked to find $k$ for which the equation has equal roots.
I am unsure of what to do.
Does this just mean when $\alpha$ = $\beta$ ? And how do I incorporate my previously found information into it?

Thank you, all help is appreciated.

Comment: can you give the original problem or screenshot it?

Comment: It's easier to just use the quadratic equation. Generally $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has (one or two) real roots iff its discriminate $b^2-4ac\ge 0.$ You can apply that hereto your second rearrangement and then simplify.

Comment: I think you mean 'discriminant' and it's supposed to be equal to $0$ in the case that the roots are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to incorporate your prior knowledge to the problem, the quadratic equation has equal roots when the discriminant is equal to zero. $$(k-1)^2 + 4(1)(1+2k) = k^2 + 6k + 5 = (k+1)(k+5) = 0 \iff k \in \{ -5, -1 \} $$

Answer (score 0):

Equal roots must satisfy the condition: $b^2 -4ac = 0$

You need to solve:

$$ (k-1)^2 -4(-1-2k) = 0 $$